# Pandas Insert a new row after every nth row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
 **L_Type   L_ID    C_Type      E_Code**
    0       1           1         9
    0       1           2         9
    0       1           3         9
    0       1           4         9
    0       2           1         2
    0       2           2         2
    0       2           3         2
    0       2           4         2
    0       3           1         3
    0       3           2         3
    0       3           3         3
    0       3           4         3
```

I need to insert a new row after every 4 row and increment the value in third column (C_Type) by 01 like below table while keeping the values same as first two columns and does not want any value in last column:

```
 L_Type     L_ID    C_Type          E_Code
    0       1           1           9
    0       1           2           9
    0       1           3           9
    0       1           4           9
    0       1           5           
    0       2           1           2
    0       2           2           2
    0       2           3           2
    0       2           4           2
    0       2           5           
    0       3           1           3
    0       3           2           3
    0       3           3           3
    0       3           4           3
    0       3           5
```

I have searched other threads but could not figure out the exact solution:

[How to insert n DataFrame to another every nth row in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450633/how-to-insert-n-dataframe-to-another-every-nth-row-in-pandas)

[Insert new rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237086/insert-new-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seelct rows by slicing, add `1` to column `C_Type` and `0.5` to index, for 100% sorrect slicing, because default method of sorting in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) is `quicksort`. Last join together, sort index and create default by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=True`:

```
df['C_Type'] = df['C_Type'].astype(int)

df2 = (df.iloc[3::4]
         .assign(C_Type = lambda x: x['C_Type'] + 1, E_Code = np.nan)
         .rename(lambda x: x + .5))
df1 = pd.concat([df, df2], sort=False).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
    L_Type  L_ID  C_Type  E_Code
0        0     1       1     9.0
1        0     1       2     9.0
2        0     1       3     9.0
3        0     1       4     9.0
4        0     1       5     NaN
5        0     2       1     2.0
6        0     2       2     2.0
7        0     2       3     2.0
8        0     2       4     2.0
9        0     2       5     NaN
10       0     3       1     3.0
11       0     3       2     3.0
12       0     3       3     3.0
13       0     3       4     3.0
14       0     3       5     NaN
```

Comment: Hi jezreal, thanks for the quick reply, when I run the code I get an error message: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @Baig - I think there are strings in `df['C_Type']` column, so use `df['C_Type'] = df['C_Type'].astype(int)` before my solution

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have changed the column from String to Int and its fine now. Is there any way I can get rid of the values in the last column for 5th row which we just inserted?